# Email links change to blue (Apple Mail mac/ios)

Tags: html, css, macos, email, html-email

I am designing a new email signature and every time I forward or reply to that email from within apple mail, it turns blue.

I can see it blue inside apple mail but also in f.i. in gmail. So it's not an issue of Apple Mail *displaying* the link blue but *making* it blue.

Here's an example code, inlined and formatted for better readability.

```html
<p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px;">
  <a 
    href="http://example.com" 
    x-apple-data-detectors="true" 
    style="font-size: 15px; 
    line-height: 18px; 
    color: #000000 !important; 
    text-decoration: underline !important; 
    text-decoration-color: #000000 !important; 
    pointer-events: visible;">
    www.example.com
</a>
</p>
```

What I tried so far:

- Creating `spans` around and inside the `a` tag.
- Setting `x-apple-data-detectors` to true and false
- Setting `<meta content="email=no" name="format-detection">` also for other link types
- Setting link text to only text, like "click here" but they still get recognised and transformed.

I can't find much about the `x-apple-data-detectors` and wonder if there's a better way to debug them.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all of the above steps and still getting nowhere with this. As a horrible workaround, I found that adding a link referencing "#" will override the blue text.

```
<a target="_blank" class="bluelinks" style="font-size: 16px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-decoration: none;" href="#">before midnight on July 4th</a>
```

Comment: This worked for me  I am displaying unformatted links 

`<a style="color:#000; text-decoration:none;" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="#">https://example.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible it the code is picking up an active state on the link?
Have you tried setting color on the active state?

Comment: Just tried it, but doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: but this brings me to the idea if some general email styling overrides the styling of the signature?

Comment: That is a known phenomenon, that emails get re-rendered on forwards/replies. There's often not much you can do in these cases

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
.appleLinksBlack a {
  color: #000000!important; 
  text-decoration: underline!important;
  }
</style>
```

And then use that class on a parent of the `<a>`, e.g.:

`<p class="appleLinksBlack" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px;">`

Comment: this is unfortunately not working neither. Also I don't know how it would play out, once the styling is inlined

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Apple Mail v16.0 (Desktop). @browsergarden It is important that you do not inline these styles. The style block has to be added to the `<head>...</head>` of the email. In addition, I used `color: inherit !important;` which translates to #3a3a3a in my case. Considering Desaintflorent’s response, this difference may be important here.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this in some CSS for HTML emails. It seems to be someone else's fix for this issue.

```
[x-apple-data-detectors] { color: inherit !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
```

I don't have access to the Apple software necessary to test this, so I'm just sharing this as an idea that I have not tested.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to work in Apple Mail v16.0. I added the exact CSS wrapped in a `<style type="text/css">...</style>` into the `<head>...</head>`.

Answer (score -1):

I spent an hour on this problem and just found out that apple mail on Mac is only changing #000000 links to blue. If you use another color ( for exemple a different dark like #1C1C1C ) you will keep you color on reply !

Comment: Tested this and it did not work! 

`<a style="color:#1C1C1C; text-decoration:none;" rel="noopener" target="_blank">https://example.com</a>`